# Python Lists Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm new to coding in general but I'm learning Python. So I've put this together but its not comparing the uInput to the 'con' list. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#countries.py
con = [('uk', 'united kingdom'), ('us', 'usa', 'america', 'united states of america'), ('japan')]
accepted = [ ]

while len(accepted) < 196:
    print("You have ", len(accepted), "/ 196 Countries!")
    uInput = input("Enter the country: ")
    print("")
    if uInput.lower() in con:
        if uInput.lower() in accepted:
            print("Already got that one!")
            print("")
        else:
            accepted.append(uInput.lower())
            print("Nice! Now for the next!")
            print("")
    else:
        print("Country not recognised, did you spell it right?")
        print("")
print("You got them all!")
```

***Edited**

So this is my code now updated, but its not check duplicates or adding them, you can enter UK as many times as you wish. But because nothings being added to the accepted list, the points don't increase either.

```
#countries.py
con = [('uk', 'united kingdom'), ('us', 'usa', 'america', 'united states of america'), ('japan')]
accepted = [ ]

while len(accepted) < 196:
    print("You have ", len(accepted), "/ 196 Countries!")
    uInput = input("Enter the country: ")
    print("")
    foundCon = False
    for conTuple in con:
        if uInput.lower() in conTuple:
            foundCon = True
            print("Nice! Now for the next!")
            print("")
            ...
        duplicate = False
        for c in accepted:
            if c in conTuple:
                duplicate = true
        if duplicate:
            print("You've already entered that one!")
            ...
    if not foundCon:
        print("Country not recognised, did you spell it right?")
        print("")
print("You got them all!")
...
```

Comment: You should flatten `con` first(except the last item) because `in` operator won't search in the inner tuples.

Comment: You're going to want to add the duplicate logic such that its nested within the if `uInput.lower() in conTuple:` statement. You only want to check for a duplicate if the uInput is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you call input you return a string, meaning that uInput is a string.

Your list con is a list of tuples.. So in the line:

```
if uInput.lower() in con:
```

you're always going to get false because a string is being compared to a tuple. It is not being compared to every element in each tuple, just the tuple as a whole. Thus uInput will never be equal to an element of con.

Perhaps try changing your code to something like this:

```
foundCon = False
for conTuple in con:
   if uInput.lower() in conTuple:
       foundCon = True
       # perform logic for matching items 
       ...
       duplicate = False
       for c in accepted:
           if c in conTuple:
               duplicate = True
       if duplicate:
           # perform logic for duplicate items
           ... 
if not foundCon:
    # perform logic for no matches
    ...
```

Comment: Ok then, that makes more sense. But what about the sets, because as Karl said above, its ok the user entering say uk, and uk being added to accepted, but united kingdom could still be used to rack up points. So how would I add the whole tuple into accepted. So basically moving ('uk', 'united kingdom') to accepted?

Comment: Added it to my answer

Comment: So I've changes my code with reference to your response, but as said above I'm still having issues.

Comment: Basically what I'm doing when finding duplicates is saying-

If this country is going to be a duplicate, the duplicate answer will be in the same tuple as uInput.

So if I already had "uk" in the accepted list and then I enter "united kingdom", here's what happens:
1) I evaluate tuples in con until I find the one with "united kingdom" in it.
2) I find that the conTuple that matches is ('uk', 'united kingdom')
3) I look at each member of accepted to see if it is in this tuple.
4) "uk" is found in ('uk', 'united kingdom'), therefore 'united kingdom' must be a duplicate this previous value "uk"

Answer (score 3):

`in` is not recursive; it can find `('uk', 'united kingdom')` in `con`, but not `'uk'` or `'united kingdom'` - neither of those is an element of `con`.

The simplest (and best) fix (of only this issue) is to check if `any` of the elements in `con` contains the input:

```
if any(uInput.lower() in c for c in con):
```

Incidentally, it would also be better to

- just convert `uInput` to lowercase once and then use it
- use a `set` for each of the `con` elements, and also for `accepted` - semantically, the `set` is intended primarily to have things looked up `in` it (as well as other mathematical `set` operations), and is optimized for that purpose, at the expense of not maintaining an ordering of the elements
- store (and check) entire `set`s of country names within `accepted`; otherwise, I could type `uk` once and `united kingdom` the second time around, and `united kingdom` would not be in `accepted` yet and I'd get double credit for that country.

Answer (score 0):

Karl Knechtel hit the main point: 'in' won't go inside your nested lists (you have a list where each element is a list). But if you do want to see if an element 'foo' exists in a list of lists 'blah' then:

```
blah=[['hi','there'],['yo','whatsup','foo']]
if('foo' in [y for y in x for x in blah]):
    print("Yep, it's in there")
```

Basically, you can quickly flatten 'blah' by using a list comprehension so that it becomes:

```
blah_flattened = ['hi','there','yo','whatsup']
```